# Standalone SVN client for Mac OS X

Tags: svn, macos

Tortoise SVN on Windows allows a single user without a network connection to create a repository on the user's machine to check code into, without needing any separate server installation or configuration. This is very useful for lone developers. Is there an SVN client for Mac OS X with this feature?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've heard good things about [Versions](http://versionsapp.com/).

Comment: I've been using Versions for a couple of months now and I tell you that is the best MacOS client around :)

Answer (score 7):

Besides just using the command line, the short list of graphical clients (just off the top of my head) for Mac OS X are:

[Versions](http://versionsapp.com/)
[svnX](http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/development_tools/svnx.html)
[Cornerstone](http://www.zennaware.com/cornerstone/)
[SCP plugin](http://scplugin.tigris.org/)

and don't forget that [Xcode](http://developer.apple.com/TOOLS/Xcode/) can natively interface with both CVS and subversion without needing external tools.

Answer (score 3):

scplugin is a Finder plugin for OS X that works similarly to TortoiseSVN on Windows in terms of user interface.

http://scplugin.tigris.org/

To create a local repository on a Mac, you can follow these instructions, which require a bit of command line wrangling:

http://www.rubyrobot.org/tutorial/subversion-with-mac-os-x

Answer (score 2):

The regular `svn` command line client can do this. Are you looking perhaps for something graphical?

Comment: I assume that he is because he mentions Tortoise SVN.

Comment: That assumption wasn't obvious. I've certainly run into people who believe TortoiseSVN *is* the Subversion client and are surprised to hear about the `svn` command.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something along the lines of [Cornerstone](http://www.zennaware.com/cornerstone/). There are a couple of great Mac OS X subversion tools, but this one in particular will allow you to create a local repository on your own computer through the GUI.

From their website:

> In fact, Cornerstone includes not just Subversion client functionality, but also the administrative tools. As a result you can create and delete repositories without having to use the command-line.

Comment: I haven't used this specific feature of Cornerstone, but in general I have been quite happy with both their product and their e-mail support.

Answer (score 1):

I've been recently looking for a good free SVN client for Mac and finally I develop with xCode and I'm using eclipse with SVN plugin and it works great. If you are familiar with eclipse it's a very good option to have in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Versions](http://versionsapp.com/) or [Syncro](http://www.syncrosvnclient.com/) (both not free).... or just command line svn/svnadmin. You may also look at distributed VCS [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/) and clients like [Murky](http://bitbucket.org/snej/murky/overview/). They provide working only locally, too - and it's easier to migrate DVCS to centralized usage (i.e. if your team grows...)